# What's the purpose of selecting scopes when creating an app versus passing scopes during install?

Tags: slack-api

I'm a bit confused when in comes to defining scopes when creating a slack app.

When I create a new app I select which scopes I will need.

When I create a 'install slack' app icon, it passes the scopes in the querystring when a user installs the app.

What is the point of passing scopes in the querystring when my App already has the scopes set when I created the app?
Which ones are relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are relevant.

The main difference is that you can choose to pass a subset of the scopes during install. That allows you to present optional features to users that require more scopes that the basic features.

**Example:**

Your app can run in two modes:

- Basic, which needs only scope A
- Full, which needs scopes A, B, C

You then define scopes A, B, C on the Oauth page of your app definition.

And on your webpage the user can choose between two versions before installing (e.g. with a radio button):

- Basic functionality
- Full functionality

When the user clicks "Add to Slack" the install link only has scopes needed for the functionality the user chose, e.g. scope A for Basic, scopes A, B, C, for Full.